# How to return a dataframe of number of duplicates based on filtering the two columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, function, filter, duplicates

```
ID group categories
1    0          red
2    1          blue
3    1          green
4    1          green
1    0          blue
1    0          blue
2    1          red
3    0          red
4    0          red
4    1          red
```

Hi, I am new to python I am trying to get the count of duplicates of ID columns based on multiple conditions on the other 2 columns. So I am filtering out red and 0 and then I wanted ID's that repeated more than once.

```
df1 = df[(df['categories']=='red')& (df['group'] == 0)]
df1['ID'].value_counts()[df1['ID'].value_counts()>1]
```

There are almost 10 categories in the categories column so I was thinking if there is any way to write a function or for loop instead of repeating the same steps. The final goal is to see how many duplicate ID's in each group given category is 'red'/'blue'/'green'. Thanks in advance
P.S : the group values doesn't change it is a binomial variable

```
output
ID    count
 1      3
 2      2
 3      2
 4      3
```

Comment: Can you provide (by editing your question) greater detail on what you're trying to do and what you mean by "a function where it can be reused".

Comment: your code doesn't output the IDs that are duplicated. application of `len` at the end will return the number of unique duplicate IDs found, and exactly what are you trying to reuse?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to remove it while posting.. Thanks

Comment: So what is expected output from your sample data? It is something different like my answer?

Comment: a data frame/ with all the duplicate ID's and the count of them..Thanks

Comment: @KANUMURIRAMYA - Can you check solution now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `groupby` with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['ID','group'])['categories'].value_counts()
print (s)
ID  group  categories
1   0      blue          2
           red           1
2   1      blue          1
           red           1
3   0      red           1
    1      green         1
4   0      red           1
    1      green         1
           red           1
Name: categories, dtype: int64

out = s[s > 1].reset_index(name='count')
print (out)
   ID  group categories  count
0   1      0       blue      2
```

Another solution is get duplicates first by filtering with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and then count:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['ID','group','categories'], keep=False)]
print (df)
   ID  group categories
4   1      0       blue
5   1      0       blue

df1 = df.groupby(['ID','group'])['categories'].value_counts().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   ID  group categories  count
0   1      0       blue      2
```

EDIT: For count categories (all rows) per `ID` use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID').size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
   ID  count
0   1      3
1   2      2
2   3      2
3   4      3
```